# Qt\application.h : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm trying to run a simple code with qt(using version 4.8) and I'm using visual studio express 2012.
I've also added the qt include to the additional library in my visual studio. but yet cannot run the program. This is the code :

```
#include <Qt\application.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(int argc, char* argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

I read that people say that, there must be a change in the .pro file in order to make to program run correctly, so I figured to paste my .pro file so you can get extra information about it.

```
CONFIG += console bootstrap
CONFIG -= qt shared app_bundle uic
DEFINES += QT_BUILD_QMAKE QT_BOOTSTRAPPED
DESTDIR = ../bin/

OBJECTS_DIR = .
MOC_DIR = .

#guts
VPATH += $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/src/corelib/global \
         $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/src/corelib/tools \
         $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/src/corelib/kernel \
         $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/src/corelib/codecs \
         $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/src/corelib/plugin \
         $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/src/corelib/xml \
         $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/src/corelib/io
INCLUDEPATH += . \
           generators \
           generators/unix \
           generators/win32 \
           generators/mac \
           generators/symbian \
           generators/integrity \
           $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/include \
           $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/include/QtCore \
           $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/qmake

VPATH += $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/tools/shared
INCLUDEPATH += $$QT_SOURCE_TREE/tools/shared

include(qmake.pri)
```

Comment: `#include <Qt\application.h>` should be `#include <QApplication>`

Comment: @drescherjm: It's been a while, but the change was between Qt3 and Qt4 IIRC. As this is tagged qt4, I agree with your comment, and think it should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is a `Qt3Support` module that you can enable in your `.pro` to allow you to use some of the deprecated classes from `Qt3` you need to use `#include <QApplication>` instead of `#include <Qt\application.h>` with `Qt4` or `Qt5`.